# Prove that for local rings $R,S$, $M_m(R)\cong M_n(S)\implies R\cong S$ and $m=n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, noncommutative-algebra, local-rings

> Prove that for local rings (not necessarily commutative, and **local** means the nonunits form a two-sided ideal) $R,S$, $M_m(R)\cong M_n(S)\implies R\cong S$ and $m=n$.

My first attempt was to consider the natural embeddings
$R\to M_m(R),\ S\to M_n(S)$ that sends, e.g. $r\in R$ to the scalar matrix $rI$ and $s\in S$ to $sI$, and then maybe restrict the isomorphism $M_m(R)\cong M_n(S)$ to the scalar matrices. The problem is I can't prove that this isomorphism maps scalar matrices to scalar matrices.

I am sensing there is something wrong with my attempt. After all, I didn't even use $R,S$ being local. Am I on the right track? How should I use the assumption that they are local rings?

---

Related:

[The same question without assuming $R,S$ local.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305539/does-m-nr-1-cong-m-nr-2-imply-r-1-cong-r-2)

[Commutative case](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38385/exotic-isomorphism-of-matrix-rings)

Comment: Hint: prove that if $R$ is local with maximal ideal $m$, and $n \geq 1$ then $mM_n(R)$ is the greatest bilateral ideal of $R$. That’s probably not enough for the whole problem, but it should prove $n=m$ and $R/m_R=S/m_S$.

Comment: @Mindlack May I ask why $mM_n(R)$  is an ideal of $R$? Shouldn't the former be matrices while the latter is a ring?

Comment: Sorry. I meant $M_n(R)$.

Comment: try Krull-Schmidt theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know a little Morita theory, the proof is pretty short.

1. $M_m(R)\cong M_n(S)$ would imply that $S$ is Morita equivalent to $R$, which amounts to $S\cong End(P_R)$ where $P$ is a finitely generated projective $R$ module.
2. Since $R$ is a local ring, a finitely generated projective module is isomorphic to $R^k$ for some $k$, and that makes $End(P_R)\cong M_k(R)$.
3. $M_k(R)$ has distinct maximal right ideals if $k>1$, so in order to be local it has to be that $k=1$, i.e. $S\cong R$.

Finally, suppose $M_n(R)\cong M_m(R)$ for some $m$ and $n$.  If $\mathfrak m$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R$, we know $R/\mathfrak m$ is a division ring. By ideal correspondence, it has to be that $M_n(R/\mathfrak m)\cong M_m(R/\mathfrak m)$. By the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, we know that $m=n$ necessarily.

Comment: Beautiful use of Morita theory !