# If the matrix rings over two Rings of the same size are isomorphic, then the scalar rings are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Let $R$ and $R'$ be rings (with 1 but no further assumptions) and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Does the following implication hold?

> If $M_n(R) \simeq M_n(R')$ then $R \simeq R'$.

If the rings are commutative then it follows from considering the centers of $M_n(R)$ and $M_n(R')$.
If the rings are division it also holds and even stronger, it holds even if the matrices are not of the same size.

I thought about considering the embeddings of $R$ in $M_n(R)$ as diagonal matrices, but since I do not want to asume anything about the isomorphism I was not able to conclude that these subrings of matrices in $M_n(R)$ and $M_n(R')$ are isomorphic. I hope someone can help me or with a proof, an idea or a counterexample. Thank you.

Comment: Multiples of the identity matrix?

Comment: @user3491648 I think this method is not applicable when $R_1,R_2$ are not commutative.

Comment: Since $R$ and $M_n(R)$ are Morita equivalent for every ring $R$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are Morita equivalent. According to wikipedia, this means that $R_2 \cong e M_k(R_1) e$ for some idempotent matrix $e \in M_k(R_1)$ such that $M_k(R_1) e M_k(R_1) = M_k(R_1)$. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: *If the rings are division it also holds and even stronger, it holds even if the matrices are not of the same size.*. Well, that "additional" stuff is nonexistent, because by Wedderburn's theorem $M_m(D_1)\cong M_n(D_2)$ for division rings $D_i$ implies $D_1\cong D_2$ and $m=n$. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2459760/29335

Comment: By the way, searching for your question should have led you to this time someone asked the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1305539/29335

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are counterexamples.

I'm not sure how easy the simplest examples are, but you could look at

*Chatters, A. W.*, [**Non-isomorphic rings with isomorphic matrix rings**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0013091500018435), Proc. Edinb. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 36, No. 2, 339-348 (1993). [ZBL0796.16022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0796.16022).

which has examples (not the first), and whose introduction gives a good overview of previous examples.

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment by Tom Goodwillie in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38385/exotic-isomorphism-of-matrix-rings) MO question, there exist rings $R,S$ such that $M_2(R) \cong M_4(S) = M_2(M_2(S))$ yet $R \ncong M_2(S)$.

Comment: Well I'd say me searching and posting a reference which answers the question is a contribution, but I've made it community wiki in case this is the norm.